# Scalatest failed with error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z"

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, hadoop, scalatest

We are working on a spark project that was working fine. Recently we had a requirement to upgrade the hadoop hdfs version to 3.1.1, so I have added an explicit dependency for hadoop-client and excluded the hadoop-client(version 2.6.5) that is getting imported automatically through spark-core in my pom file as shown below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.0</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
          <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The maven build without tests is getting succeeded and even the application is running fine on the spark cluster. But the scalatests are failing with the error

```
"ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:640)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1223)"
```

We are using the maven-surefire-plugin and scalatest plugin in our pom file. We have the hadoop binary for 2.7.1 copied under lib directory within our project and the HADOOP_HOME environment variable under scalatest dependency is set to this path. After making the above dependency changes to get hadoop-client 3.1.1, the maven build with tests started failing. I tried to download the hadoop 3.1.1 binary (with winutils and hadoop.dll) and update my HADOOP_HOME to point to that path but still getting the same error.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
         <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m</argLine>
         <skipTests>true</skipTests>
         <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/scalatest-reports</reportsDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
         <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx1024m</argLine>
         <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/scalatest-reports</reportsDirectory>
         <junitxml>jUnitResults</junitxml>
         <parallel>false</parallel>
         <skipTests>false</skipTests>
         <environmentVariables>
         **<HADOOP_HOME>${project.basedir}/../lib/hadoop-2.7.1</HADOOP_HOME>**
         </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>test</id>
          <goals>
             <goal>test</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any pointers to fix this issue specific to running scalatests using build is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using <useZincServer>false<useZincServer> while building the spark, How you are building the spark tho? using makedistribuation.sh? or mvn install package?

Comment: Building spark project using mvn clean install

Comment: Try makedistribution.sh or mvn clean package